"Possible duplicate" comment is not deleted after dup-hammering a question in staging ground
I closed the question in Staging Ground as a duplicate. Because I have a gold badge, the question has been closed immediately and has obtained the banner

This question already has an answer here:

But at the same time the comment

Possible duplicate of ...

has been added automatically. This comment has NOT been autodeleted as noted in that recent meta question.
I find presence of the given comment to be very confusing when the question is closed.

On a side-note, seems like some Onboarding for Reviewers is sill hard needed as the first 2 Commenters/Reviewers in the SG-Question (8k and 10k Rep) started directly to answer it instead of reviewing it to make it fit to be eventually posted on 'Main' (or trying to search for a Duplicate)...

@chivracq I'd first like to see some kind of poll into how, when and why people do that. Because it wouldn't surprise me that they're so zoned out or zoned in that they hardly notice it's a staging ground post and are just commenting as they always would and the problem is more that staging ground posts appear willy-nilly.

This is intended and not specific to the dupe-hammer. The comment from the Community user is added to all Staging Ground questions marked/closed as a duplicate (and not just when voting to mark it as such).
This behavior is more obvious with duplicate closures from users without a gold tag badge:

The first user votes to mark the question as a duplicate
This adds the comment you expected to be deleted
A second user votes to mark the question as a duplicate
The comment from the first user is created and the Community user creates a new comment saying "Possible duplicate of <link>"

The comment mentioned in the question you linked that is removed is the comment of the user marking the question as a duplicate.
As askers often just look at the comments and not the banner they are seeing, this tells them what to look for.
It can also be useful if a reviewer later changes the state to "Major Changes" or similar. In that case, the duplicate comment is the only thing linking to the duplicate target (AFAIK).

According to the linked question, the intended behavior is auto removing the comment after the question is closed. But this didn't happen in my case.

As I mentioned, the intended behavior of auto-removing is for a different comment ("This question is similar to: ..."). The "Possible duplicate of ..." comment isn't intended to be removed automatically but is supposed to be closed/marked as duplicates.
